# Android permission for broadcast PACKAGE_REMOVED/PACKAGE_ADDED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

My BroadcastReceiver object needs to listen for the `PACKAGE_REMOVED` / `PACKAGE_ADDED` intents. What permissions are needed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any permissions for this. Have a look here:
https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/697e7e7cc6dd3d1f?pli=1